# key board event on dropdown combobox mfc

Tags: combobox, mfc, dropdownbox

How to handle delete key on dropdown of combobox which is created with style CBS_DROPDOWNLIST?
I want to delete the items in the dropdow list when user presses delete key. Please someone explain how to handle this on a combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Either use PreTranslateMessage in the parent dialog to fetch the VK_DELETE key. Or subclass the list control when the combo box drops down.

You can get the handle of the list control with [GetComboBoxInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)